# Overriding Groovy's java.util.Date toString method

Tags: grails, groovy, elasticsearch

I have a Grails (version 2.5.0 ; Groovy version 2.4.3) application where I had a CustomPropertyEditorRegistry to override date formats when using fieldvalue.

I installed ElasticSerach Grails plugin version 0.0.4.4 , after installation I noticed the custom property editor was not working anymore. In an attempt to temporarily work around the problem, I decided to simply override the java.util.Date's toString() method using Groovy's meta programming.

I added this to Bootstrap.groovy:

```
Date.metaClass.toString = {
   return delegate.format("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
}
```

However, when I went to the Grails console (using the Grails Console plugin):

```
new Date("Fri Jun 12 12:36:02 EDT 2015") as String == "Fri Jun 12 12:36:02 EDT 2015"
new Date("Fri Jun 12 12:36:02 EDT 2015").toString() == "06/12/2015 12:36"

println(new Date("Fri Jun 12 12:36:02 EDT 2015")) // prints Fri Jun 12 12:36:02 EDT 2015
println(new Date("Fri Jun 12 12:36:02 EDT 2015").toString()) // prints 06/12/2015 12:36
```

Any help figuring out the custom property issue and/or overriding Date toString() would be appreciated. I have opened an issue on the ElasticSearch Grails Plugin GitHub, issue #115 as well

**EDIT:**

I've performed some more tests with both Grails and Groovy.

I created a new Grails 2.5.0 application with this code in the Bootstrap.groovy:

```
Date.metaClass.toString = {
    return delegate.format("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
}
```

and added this to the index.gsp view:

```
<ul>
    <li>new Date().toString() == ${new Date().toString()}</li>
    <li>new Date() == ${new Date()}</li>
    <li>new Date() as String == ${new Date() as String}</li>
</ul>

/*Output:
new Date().toString() == 06/15/2015 10:32
new Date() == Mon Jun 15 10:32:33 EDT 2015
new Date() as String == Mon Jun 15 10:32:33 EDT 2015
*/
```

I also launched the groovyConsole with Groovy version 2.4.3 with this code/output:

```
Date.metaClass.toString = {
    return delegate.format("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
}

println(new Date())
println(new Date() as String)
println(new Date().toString())

/*Output:
06/15/2015 10:38
Mon Jun 15 10:38:12 EDT 2015
Mon Jun 15 10:38:12 EDT 2015
*/
```

So this does appear to be an inconsistency in Groovy where it is not calling the toString() from the modified metaclass method, unless I'm doing something incorrectly or misunderstanding something.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior. Unless Grails is causing here something the `as String` variant should result in a toString() call. Which then of course has the same output. So all I can say is that Groovy by itself is not causing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't find anything wrong with the overrides and it does work when printing the instance alone `new Date()`, I believe the issue is that Java is calling the `toString()` method directly rather than letting Groovy control the method invocation process which would result in executing the `asType()` and `toString()` overridden methods. I'm not sure of a clean workaround, and I'm still unsure why the Custom Property Editors stopped working when ElasticSearch plugin was installed.

Answer (score 2):

You said you're using the Groovy console, but you mean you're running `grails console`, right? BootStrap doesn't run when launching the console, only in `run-app` and tests. If you run the `toString` override in the console and then run your sample code it should work fine.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I am using the Grails Console plugin. So Bootstrap should have run, correct?

Comment: Yes, since you're accessing the running app.

Comment: So it seems that there is still something wrong here if as String should call .toString() , but the output when printing those two statements are different (see edit with more details).

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought about "`as String`"
 .. if you redefine `asType` method:

```
Date.metaClass.asType = { Class clazz ->
 return "Hello"
}

(new Date()) as String
===> Hello
```

but still:

```
new Date()
===> Wed Jul 01 20:12:35 EEST 2015
```